# How to make tabindex in openerp fields

Tags: odoo

I want to change the tabindex in a form in opererp
how can I change it in the xml file or the python code
I am using openerp 6.1

example to what I need
in sales order form ,user want to change the focus of the element using tab button
he need to write first the order reference field then go to customer service field using a tab button,but when I press tab I go to the date button not the custom service even that the date button has a default value

Thanks

Comment: have you clear idea, what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit and change both the models (defined in python files) and views (defined in xml files). More details about inheritance can be found here [Object Inheritance](https://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/object_inherit.html/)
and [Inheritance in Views](https://doc.openerp.com/6.0/developer/2_6_views_events/views/view_inheritence/)

Comment: I can override them but what about the tabindex,I just need to add tabindex to some fields because some fields have a default value and I don't need to change them so no need of tab

Comment: @ahmed any update on the tabindex implementation in odoo field?

Answer (score 0):

you can overwrite the original xml arch in your view and change the sequence of pages as per your requirement

like:

```
<record id="**account.invoice_supplier_form**" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">account.invoice.supplier.form</field>
            <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
            <field name="priority">2</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Supplier Invoice" version="7.0">
```

as shown above you can write the same xml arch as define in account for supplier invoice,

and  you can now change sequence of pages

hope this help

Comment: I can't change the sequence of the element,the problem is there are some fields have a default value and I don't want to write on them when press tab

Comment: I can not change the sequence of element they need the same sequence,i.e they need the first field to by the serial number and the second field to be the date with a default of today and the third is the title and when I focus in the serial number field and press tab go to title not the date field